# Creating default set-ups for commonly used code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This is a pretty minor annoyance, but I noticed that every time I create a class in Visual Studio there are a few things that I would like to be automatically-generated for me. For instance, all of my classes start with a log4net declaration. It's only one line of code, but it's annoying having to find a class where I declared it in to copy/paste from.

In addition, there are multiple common 'usings' which I use, but that are not created by default.

Is it possible to setup VS to do this?

Comment: do really *all* of your classes start with a log4net decl? may I ask what kind of code/which layer you are writing?

Comment: I've been writing a web dashboard in ASP.NET AJAX. I've been given an API to provide me with data so I'm really only working on view/controller aspects (not MVC yet, but you get the idea.)

Classes which are merely for highlighting an enumeration do not need logging... but surely I should have a means of seeing what's going on with anything that could do work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to edit the default Visual Studio Class template. A walkthrough of the process can be found [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/).

Answer (score 2):

From the File menu, select "Export Template".

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own item/project templates. Here is a primer from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx

Basically you'd create your own custom class template.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

- [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx)
- [How to: Manually Create Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113.aspx):

  - Create a project and project item.
  - Modify the project item until it is ready to be saved as a template.
  - As appropriate, modify the code file to indicate where parameter replacement should occur. For more information about parameter replacement, see [How to: Substitute Parameters in a Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx).
  - Create an XML file and save it by using a .vstemplate file name extension, in the same directory as your new item template.
  - Author the .vstemplate XML file to provide item template metadata. For more information, see the example in the following section.
  - Save the .vstemplate file and close it.
  - In Windows Explorer, select the files you want to include in your template, right-click the selection, click Send To, and then click Compressed (zipped) Folder. The files that you selected are compressed into a .zip file.
  - Copy the .zip file and paste it in the user item template location. In Windows Vista, the default directory is ..\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates. For more information, see [How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what you are asking for, one option is to declare code snippets. This will allow you to leave the standard class alone (not change the template) and add in the pieces that you require without having to find a class with it. However, if all your classes for every project you create requires the same basic set of code then Templates are the way to go.

[C# Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

How to use them can be found [How to Use Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)